# Change package.xml of extension and generate tgz file

Tags: magento-1, extensions, package, downloader

I need to edit a `package.xml` file of a extension.

There is a php restriction to that module and I need to increase it, so that I can install it on my store. I know it works well with that php version.

But when changing the `package.xml` file, how can I regenerate a tgz file, so that I can upload the module again in the Magento Downloader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Clean and error free way

To do that you need to **ensure your modules XML file is placed in your `var/connect` folder.** It must be named based on your module name for example: `Vendor_Module.xml` and it contains all the info / requirements / files path of your module.

Then you go to the backend under **System > Magento Connect > Package Extensions**.

You choose **"Load Existing Package" tab** and choose your module in the list.

From here it will load all your modules information and you'll be able to edit the PHP requirement from the form.

Once you're done, save and generate the package, your module tgz and its corresponding XML file will be updated.

### Quick and dirty way

Edit the `package.xml` file, find the following XML node and edit it:

```
<dependencies>
    <required>
       <php>
           <min>MIN</min>
           <max>MAX</max>
       </php>
   </required>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! When I want to edit the quick and dirty way, by editing the package.xml, how can I than create the right tgz file? So that I can upload it in the Magento connect Manager?

Comment: @HenkZ that you can't you'll have to use the backend for that